# Windows message WM_QUIT and WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, loops, winapi, getmessage

I have to catch `WM_QUIT` message in WPF but there is a problem.

```
IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
```

WndProc works fine and catch all messages except `WM_QUIT`.

Msdn says:

> The WM_QUIT message is not associated with a window and therefore will never be received through a window's window procedure. It is retrieved only by the GetMessage or PeekMessage functions.

Is there any way to catch this message in WPF? Maybe with `ComponentDispatcher`?

There is also:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getmessage

Which can be used in C# environment.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain why you want to do this a native alternative can be suggested.

Comment: As you found out, that message really isn't a message. Think of it as a flag, that instructs the message retrieval functions to synthesize an object that has a `WM_QUIT` message ID. [Why is there a special PostQuitMessage function?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453) explains some of the details. It is **very** unlikely, that your proposed solution will get you anywhere. Maybe you should ask about your problem instead.

Comment: I want to shutdown my app gracefully. C++ program that sends wm_quit cant be changed .

Comment: Your main windows Closing event does not get raised?

Comment: Thing is that i have splash screen and if c++ app post wm_quit while it splash still active it close splash but main window continue it is responsive but without graphic

Comment: The obvious solution would then be to fix **that** bug, instead of attempting a highly intrusive solution, only to keep going with a buggy implementation. And by *"bug"* I am referring to an external program sending a `WM_QUIT` message. I already linked you to information, why `WM_QUIT` is special, and why faking it is wrong.

Comment: Once after splash screen goes away works good. App close when wm_quit is posted

Comment: So the c++ should not post that message? What do you mean by faking it?

Comment: Stop posting that message. Fix the real problem.

Comment: Why is the C++ program posting that message? That message is not allowed to be posted; if one program wants to ask another program to close, it will need to do so in a cooperative way (or if all else fails, with WM_CLOSE, which is a different message that is equivalent to clicking the Close button on the titlebar and would generate a Closing event in your WPF window).

Comment: So the real problem is that message and cannot be handled properly?

Comment: No, the **real** problem is, that you aren't following the contract. The only way to generate a `WM_QUIT` message is by calling `PostQuitMessage`. Everything else is a bug. You need to fix that bug. Your WPF application has no trouble responding to a **real** `WM_QUIT` message.

Comment: Problem is that i dont work on that c++ app i have nothing to do with. its made by my fellow at work . He said that they had no problem sending this message to win forms. Wpf is responding on that message  but i cannot get this message in wpf it just terminate

Comment: And when splash window is active mainwindow is hidden and that hidden window do not get closed if that message is send when splash is still active

Comment: If wpf has no problem responding to wm_quit how to get that message in code behind or it just call window close method?

Comment: Their code is being lucky; they are still breaking the rules, and Microsoft are well within their power to make trying to post WM_QUIT manually do nothing at some point in the future. They should fix their code to use WM_CLOSE on a window to request a close. Then, you would just need to handle the Closing event in WPF. Your code does not need to be changed; theirs does. If you can't convince them to do it, convince your bosses to force them to using the documentation on MSDN and The Old New Thing that has been linked here already and may be linked here by others later.

Comment: So the wm_quit should not be used at all?

Comment: I ment that MV_QUIT can be used for certain examples, but not for closing apps gracefully.

Comment: No. You'll never even get WM_QUIT; in a traditional Windows message pump (which WPF uses internally), the presence of a WM_QUIT is indicated by a special return value from the message pump's "get next message" functions that says "okay, the message loop is over; time to go home". And even if you did get a WM_QUIT, it would not have an associated window handle.

Comment: Aha this is kind a wpf thing?

Comment: It posible with winforms?

Comment: You are inverting history. All of this is explained by the rules of the Windows API. Since both Windows Forms, as well as WPF re-use the available infrastructure, those rules apply to those frameworks just as much. In other words: Sending a `WM_QUIT` message is meaningless for any application, regardless of the framework it uses.

Comment: But what about componentdispatcher https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348549(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In combination of that: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getmessage

Comment: ThreadFilterMessage and ThreadPreprocessMessage events follow the standard rules for delegate invocations. Delegates are invoked in an unspecified order, and all delegates are invoked even if the first one marks the message as handled.

Comment: Why don't you just solve the problem instead of fixating on your bogus solution

Comment: Get your coworkers to ask if they're doing it right on here then, if they're overruling you and forcing you to do something you literally cannot do.

Comment: If your co-workers need a test-case, have them launch notepad.exe, gather it's main window handle using Spy++, and write a simple application that sends a `WM_QUIT` message to it. Closely observe, that this has no effect at all.